# Magento 1.9.2.4: Show category images in top navigation menu

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Hi I am using copy of rwd theme to make a custom theme. What i need to do is to show category image in the top menu, I am trying to make it happen through renderer.phtml. Tried a lot of thing but nothing worked. Here is code from renderer.phtml.

```
 <?php
            $html = '';

            $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
            $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
            $childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

            $counter = 1;
            $childrenCount = $children->count();

            $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
            $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $child->setLevel($childLevel);
                $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
                $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
                $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

                $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel;
                $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

                $html .= '<li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

                $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

                if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
                }

                $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

                if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
                    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
                    $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .' view-all">';
                    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
                    $html .=             $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
                    $html .=         '</a>';
                    $html .=     '</li>';
                    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
                    $html .= '</ul>';
                }

                if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }

                $html .= '</li>';

                $counter++;
            }

            return $html;
```

Comment: You need to show sub-categories with categories images ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: Have you add code anywhere for display sub category image ?